# How to close a form in UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, visual-c#-express-2010

I created a UserControl with the buttons `Save`, `Close` and `Cancel`. I want to close the form without saving on the Cancel button, prompt a message to save on the Close button and Save without closing on the Save button. Normally, I would have used `this.Close()` on the Cancel button, but the UserControl doesn't have such an option. So I guess I have to set a property for that.

Scrolling down the `"Questions that may already have your answer"` section, I came across this question: [How to close a ChildWindow from an UserControl button loaded inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803451/how-to-close-a-childwindow-from-an-usercontrol-button-loaded-inside-it) I used the following C# code:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProjectInfo infoScreen = (ProjectInfo)this.Parent;
    infoScreen.Close();
}
```

This does the job for one screen, but I wonder if I have to apply this code for all the screen I have? I think there should be a more efficient way. So my question is: Do I need to apply this code for every form I have, or is there another (more efficient) way?

Comment: Controls should not mess with their parent, raise an event instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use

```
((Form)this.TopLevelControl).Close();
```

Comment: Mine answer did the trick for what I use it for (indeed the control is directly embedded in the form). But I like yours better

Answer (score 7):

you can use the FindForm method available for any control:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form tmp = this.FindForm();
    tmp.Close();
    tmp.Dispose();
}
```

Do not forget to Dispose the form to release resources.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You helped my life. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You also can close one form in any part of the code using a remote thread:

```
            MyNamespace.MyForm FormThread = (MyNamespace.MyForm)Application.OpenForms["MyForm"];
            FormThread.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the simple answer :) I all ready thought of something like that.

To close a WinForm in a `ButtonClicked Event` inside a UserControl use the following code:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form someForm = (Form)this.Parent;
    someForm.Close();
}
```

Comment: it depends if the usercontrol is directly embedded in the form or in other sub-controls. using TopLevelControl should make the trick